# how to check how many voice channel my discord bot is in?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I want my bot(coded in discord.js) to show how many voice channels my discord bot is in, and I have no idea how to do that.

Can I get some help? I would offer My bot's premium silver edition to those who helped just dm `A350-1000#6715` on discord for redeem code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.voiceConnections`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=voiceConnections).

Like this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(client.voiceConnections.size)
});
```

Comment: Changed to client.voice.connections in recent Discord.js versions.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the discord.js docs, I found under the class `Client` a `.channels` property that returns a `ChannelManager` which helps handle every channel the client is handling. In the `ChannelManager` class, there is a property `.cache` that returns a collection of channels, so I suppose you can loop through the collection and count every channel that is a voice channel, every `Channel` object has a property `.type` which returns a string.

Discord.js docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client